# IOS (iPad mini) scanning frequency is reduced after 2 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a bluetooth peripheral that is advertising every 10ms. The iPad mini that I am running my code on picks up about 40-65 every second (roughly 18ms) for the first 2 minutes then after that it seems to enter a lowered power state with reduced scanning frequency and only picks up between 6-12 every second.

This seems intentional and I assume it is to reduce power consumption but I am unable to find any reference to it by Apple.

I've worked around it by calling the following code every 100 seconds via an NSTimer:

```
    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil 
    options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
```

However, I would like to learn more about this behaviour in the case of a more elegant solution or if I should avoid doing such things altogether.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm running into a similar situation!